# Django Bootstrap Datepicker Plus loads with no default date or placeholder

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, datepicker

I'm using Django with Date-Picker-Plus. Everything works correctly, except the date picker displays/has no value until you click the box. [image: See attached photo.]

I have dug through all the documentation and can't find any references elsewhere of someone having this problem. I'm not familiar with js much so this is a bit foreign to me.

Heres the documentation I've gone thru:

https://django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Usage.html
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate

```
    class Meta:
        model = Jobs_DB
        fields = ['date_scheduled']
        widgets = {
            'date_scheduled': DatePickerInput(
                options={
                    "format": "MM-DD-YYYY",  # moment date-time format
                    "showClose": True,
                    "showClear": True,
                    "showTodayButton": True,
                    'defaultDate': True,
                },
            ),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it in JavaScript. The Python package datetimepickler_plus does not document how to set a date/time option, and I was too lazy to debug this or look into the code. This is the JS code (jQuery required):

```js
const now = new Date();
$('.input-group.date')
  .find("input").data("DateTimePicker")
  .defaultDate(now)
  .maxDate(now);
```

This sets the initial date (defaultDate call) and the maximum date (maxDate call). You probably have to adjust the query selector to suit your needs.